# SwiftMailer how to configure it with google?

Tags: symfony

I have installed sendmail and it's work's with gmail so it's not a problem.
In swift mailer config yaml it's looks like:

```
swiftmailer:
  transport:  smtp
  encryption: tls
  auth_mode:  login
  host:       smtp.gmail.com
  username:   (this is my email)
  password:   (this is my pass)
  port:       587
```

in .env:
    MAILER_URL=gmail://username:password@localhost

I get this error:

```
Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. 
OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
```

I don't know because if i use mail function it's work's fine.

Comment: I'm not sure which Symfony version you are using. It looks like you have both Symfony 3 and 4 ways in your code.

Comment: It seems that your problem is not necessarily with your configuration, but with the ssl connection not being able to verify the certificate it receives from Google. Look at [this issue in guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/819) for a similar problem and how to solve it. You might also want to search for `php ssl verify certificate` to find questions related to this problem. If you then stilll have trouble getting it to work, feel free to append your question or open a new one.